# EGIT rejected non-fast forward

Tags: eclipse, egit

I'm on Eclipse 4.2.1 (Java) and trying to use EGIT. My account is all set up on Github. No one else is working on it so there are no changes. I have a very simply project containing a single file with one print statement.
I created my local repo and added the project. (project explorer shows: [gitrepo1 master])

In project explorer:
right click on project -> team -> remote -> push
But I get: master: HEAD [rejected - non-fast-forward]

I've configured the push:
Branch -> master 
URI -> ssh.git@github....
Ref mappings -> HEAD:/refs/heads/master

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

We had this problem, because we amended a commit after pushing it.

The solution was to merge origin/master (in Branches > Remote tracking), then push.

Answer (score 2):

egit works by using jgit which is an implementation of git that is using java. the best thing to do is verify that the repo works with the normal git client. From your question it is not possible to know exactly how things ore configured.

When you get the error message that you could not do a push because it is not a fast forward, it means you need to do a pull first then, do the push, so try that.

Comment: When I try to pull I get:
Could not get advertised Ref for branch refs/remotes/origin/master

Comment: it looks to me that you don't have a remote tracking branch setup correctly. did you clone the project with egit ?

Answer (score 1):

Same cause as Bernát: I amended a commit after pushing it. Merge failed because of conflicts.

My way out: Context menu 'Team/Reset' selection 'Remote Tracking'/'origin master' option 'Mixed'. After that all my changes since last push were marked and I could commit and push.